# Main not seeing my function in input.h

Tags: c, header-files

`input.c` file:

```
#include "input.h"
void file_processing( FILE *course_file, FILE *student_file )
{
    char buf[256], line[256];
    ........
}
```

`input.h` file:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <string.h>

void process_command( char command[256] );

void file_processing( FILE *course_file, FILE *student_file );

#endif
```

`main.c` file:

```
#include "input.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    .........
    file_processing(course_file, student_file);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is throwing me this error:

```
main.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.c:53:46: error: ‘file_processing’ was not declared in this scope
```

Anyone can give me some hints on what to look at?

**UPDATE:** 
After some extra coding, I'm getting a different error.

```
/tmp/ccJ4nsnm.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to `file_processing(_IO_FILE*, _IO_FILE*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What compiler are you using - if it is gcc you can use the `-E` option to give you some clues how the preprocessor is reading your code

Comment: Is `input.h` file in the directory where the `main.c` is ? If not, did you specify the compiler where to look for the headers ?

Comment: I'm using gcc, and using -E, input.h only appears once (# 1 "input.h" 1) and nothing else appears. It is in the same directory.

Comment: You need to use it with the main.c file

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it with main.c, Fred answered the question. :)

Comment: You header includes `<string.h>`, which isn't obviously necessary, but doesn't include `<stdio.h>` which obviously is necessary.  The mismatched name in the header guard is suspicious, but not definitively a problem.  If you're showing us all the code in `main.c`, then the only conclusion can be that the `input.h` being included is the one you provided.  Does your compilation line include `-I.` (so the header is included from the current directory)? Look at the preprocessed output to see what the compiler's seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it interesting that your multiple inclusion protection does not match your file name:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
```

Did you get that from another .h file that's also being included?

Comment: @user1043625: Probably a copy/paste error. Happens all the time.

Comment: @FredLarson Am I missing something stupid, why does it have to match (except for good coding standards)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: It wouldn't HAVE to match, but it commonly would. It looks like a header guard that belongs to a `student.h` file, doesn't it? So I thought it likely there was another header not mentioned in the question that was also being included and using the same header guard. Looks like I was right. 8v)

Comment: @FredLarson Totally a lateral thinking answer - I did not even consider that to be the issue - nice find!